# Ejabberd connect to node

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to connect with ejabberd server with following command

```
 # ejabberdctl start
```

but, it gives me below error.

```
    Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@localhost: nodedown
```

Please help me to figure out this. thank you

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that the server @localhost is not running.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check the service, terminal code below.

```
ps aux | grep ejabberd
```

if any unwanted servicer running kill that,terminal code below.
eg.
kill 14056

and stop the ejabberd service ,terminal code below.

```
ejabberdctl stop
```

or

```
/sbin/ejabberdctl stop
```

close the terminal and reopen terminal and start the ejabberd service,terminal code below.

ejabberdctl start

or

/sbin/ejabberdctl start

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your directory to the folder which contains ejabberdctl file:

```
cd /Applications/ejabberd/bin
```

Then you have to use this code to start ejabberd:

```
./ejabberdctl start
```

you can also use this to see the status of your ejabberd server:

```
./ejabberdctl status
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if service is running or no  then `./ejabberdctl start`. If you still have errors you should post your log because I can't see what is happening on your machine